# rPhenograph file is a "large communities (68 elements, 2.5Mb) How to plot it? ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I used some raw-output files from our flow cytometer which tells me in .csv which intensities it measures at which wavelength for every event/cell.

This resulted in a .csv with around 25000 cells and around 240 measuring points.

Importing the .csv file into R-Studio and removing some measurements yielded a matrix with 25000 obs x 73 variables.

Then I used rPhenograph to calculate the neighborhoods, which worked well.
But now it seems to be a dataframe or something that I genuinely have no idea how to plot it.

```
Data1 <- read_csv("CD4_3.csv", skip=17)
Data_selected <- select(Data2, ends_with(".A"))

rpheno_out <- Rphenograph(Data_selected)
```

I hoped to get a plot which looks/resembles a tSNE plot.
Instead, I only got an error-code telling me that ggplot can't handle it.

```
ggplot(rpheno_out) + geom_point()
```

> Fehler: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
>   `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class communities

Comment: Could you include some example data of `rpheno_out` ? (using `dput(head(my_data))` for example)

Comment: Also, if you haven't attempted it yet, please try using the `plot()` function for the `rpheno_out` object. Custom classes sometimes have their associated default plot functions in their packages so it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the "plot" function:

"Fehler in plot(y, vertex.color = col, mark.groups = mark.groups, edge.color = edge.color,  : 
  Argument "y" fehlt (ohne Standardwert)"
Error in plot, argument y missing (with no default).

dput(head(rpheno_out)) gave me this :
structure(list(`1` = c("62", "81", "153", "154", "208", "300", 
"373", "519", "592", "792", "811", "884", "1030", "1103", "1176", 
"1230", "1322", "1395", "1468", "1541", "1614", "1687", "1760", 
 and the list goes on and on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the `Rphenograph()` function returns ; the doc states :

> A simple R implementation of the phenograph
>   [PhenoGraph](http://www.cell.com/cell/abstract/S0092-8674(15)00637-6)
>   algorithm, which is a clustering method designed for high-dimensional
>   single-cell data analysis. It works by creating a graph ("network")
>   representing phenotypic similarities between cells by calclating the
>   Jaccard coefficient between nearest-neighbor sets, and then
>   identifying communities using the well known [Louvain
>   method](https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/) in this graph.

This only builds clusters on your data based on the information you provide. The output has no dimensionally reduced version of your input.

If you want to see what your clustering looks like, then you have to apply your favorite dimension-reduction analysis and plot color-coding with the cluster info from `Rphenograph()`.

To give you an example, I've done this on the provided code from the function's doc :

```
library(cytofkit)

## Example from Rphenograph's doc
iris_unique <- unique(iris) # Remove duplicates
data <- as.matrix(iris_unique[,1:4])
Rphenograph_out <- Rphenograph(data, k = 45)


## Added bit to see the results
pca <- prcomp(iris_unique[,1:4], retx = T, rank. = 2)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(pca$x, col=Rphenograph_out$membership, lwd=3,
     main="Color by Rphenograph cluster")
plot(pca$x, col=iris_unique$Species, lwd=3,
     main="Color by Species")
```

Results in :
[image]

Comment: Ah ok, then I have to look into that. Sorry, I am just a simple beginner and often have difficulties properly transferring the guides to my problems.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Just a tip for future troubles : it's worth messing around with objects to see what's inside (plotting `head()`s and `names()` and such). A little tinkering can go a long way ; know what's in your data.

Comment: Yeah head() and names() I use frequently, but I think I am not yet proficient enough to always draw the right conclusions out of it :D
Thanks again!